# Integration by parts for f(x).g(x)

Tags: calculus, integration

[image: Question]

I have shown the first part by using integration by parts, but at am at a lost as to how I will be able to employ that result to be able to prove the second part. Any help on how to proceed is seriously appreciated!

Edit: So I have looked at the induction process but am still confused. This is where I am at right now:

$$\left(\int_{a}^b g(x)f(x)=\frac{(-1)^{k}}{c^{k}}\int_{a}^b g(x)f^{(k)}(x)\right)\times\frac{-1}{c}$$
$$\frac{-1}{c}\int_{a}^b g(x)f(x)=\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{c^{k+1}}\int_{a}^b g(x)f^{(k)}(x)$$
$$-\int_{a}^b g(x)f(x)=\frac{c(-1)^{k+1}}{c^{k+1}}\int_{a}^b g(x)f^{(k)}(x)$$
$$-\int_{a}^b g(x)f(x)=\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{c^{k+1}}\int_{a}^b cg(x)f^{(k)}(x)$$
$$-\int_{a}^b g(x)f(x)=\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{c^{k+1}}\int_{a}^b g'(x)f^{(k)}(x)$$

From here I have no idea how to produce $f^{(k+1)}(x)$ inside the integral, or whether this was the right way to approach solving this problem. Any pointers with how to proceed would be awesome!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. Use induction, and the best thing: You have allready done the base step. And almost the induction step, as if $f$ is identically zero at $a$ and $b$, so is $f^{(k)}$, now apply a) again.

Comment: just as a reminder, would I then need to prove that this works for the case where n=k+1 to show that this is always true